# Convert Scala Wrapper$MapWrapper to a Java Map

Tags: scala, wsdl, playframework-2.0

I have the following code inside a Wsdl2Java generated class:

```
context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS)
```

The class of the object at runtime is

```
scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper
```

How can I convert this object to a Java map?

Thank you in advance.

---

Uf... there is no conversion to be done... it is a map already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper` [extends](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$@MapWrapper[A,B]extendsAbstractMap[A,B]) `java.util.AbstractMap` (which, in turn, implements `java.util.Map`), so it is kind of already a java map and I believe you don't have to do anything.